# Javascript eventListener only working in some areas of the element

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

So i was building a burger menu responsive navbar. I finished up most of the working but i got stuck at one point. The problem is i have applied the javascript onClick event listener on the div `.burger` so that it changes the opacity of the `.nav-container`  to 1. Up until to this point this works fine. The problem is this click event only works in some areas on the `.burger`. Like if clicked on of the lines in it or somewhere to the right. I can't seem to find the problem. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Here is my code

```js
function showNav() {
  var nav = document.getElementById("nav");

  nav.classList.add("show-nav");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.line1,
.line2,
.line3 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.nav-heading {
  flex: 4;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.burger {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 40%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}

.nav-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(-20%);
  transform-origin: left;
  ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    list-style-type: none;
    li {
      flex: 1;
      padding: 15px;
    }
  }
}

.show-nav {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(20%);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-heading">
      <h1>Navbar</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="burger" onclick="showNav()">

      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>

    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="nav-container" id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: You could remove "flex:1" from 'burger' to avoid the red space to the right of it.

Comment: Your `.nav-container` is overlapping the bottom of your `.burger`.

Answer (score 1):

Just put z-index = 1 on .burger.

```
.burger {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 40%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to bring your menu up front , you can add `position:relative` + `z-index:1;` to make sure it stands on top.

You also add the rule `cursor: pointer;` to show it is a clickable element :)

For the class you add, you could use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) `.` [`toggle()`](http://%5D%5B1%5D) , so it shows/hides alternatively.

example

```js
function showNav() {
  var nav = document.getElementById("nav");

  nav.classList.toggle("show-nav");
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 2%;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.line1,
.line2,
.line3 {
  width: 40px;
  height: 8px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 3px;
}

.nav-heading {
  flex: 4;
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.burger {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 40%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1
}

.nav-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .2s ease-in-out;
  transform: translateY(-20%);
  transform-origin: left;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 15px;
}

li a {
  color: black;
}

.show-nav {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: translateY(20%);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-heading">
      <h1>Navbar</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="burger" onclick="showNav()">

      <div class="line1"></div>
      <div class="line2"></div>
      <div class="line3"></div>

    </div>

  </div>


  <div class="nav-container" id="nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>

    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the width of

```
.nav-container {
  width: 30%;
}
```

so it doesn't overlap the burger. In general your CSS structure is not good.

Comment: like what should let the width be. make it auto